# Scala Joda Time Format Malformed

Tags: scala, jodatime

I can't find many Scala examples with Joda time especially with formatting but here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-12-11T13:35:45.732-05:00" is malformed at "15-12-11T13:35:45.732-05:00"
```

Here is the code:

```
val now = DateTime.now.toString()
val dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
val timeForm = dtf.parseDateTime(now)
```

Most of the java exmaples all seem to work fine with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Scala. `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` means the string will start with month, then day, etc. (see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html for the meaning of characters in the patterns). `2015-12-11T13:35:45.732-05:00` obviously doesn't. Either use `val now = dtf.printDateTime(DateTime.now)` to print current datetime in the same format you are planning to parse, or use the correct format to parse it.